# My dollar sign doesn't work on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I want to just increment a variable of Number of touch and change the name of my button which the number of the touch. I watch a YouTube video which do that i want to do and i want to do the same BUT my $ doesn't work like in the YouTube video.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       var NumberofTouches = 0

       button.setOnClickListener {
           NumberofTouches ++
           button.text='$NumberofTouches touch'
        }
    }
  }
```

I expect the $ are in yellow in the button.text and isn't ( like the var or super for example)

link of the YouTube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Vwx2drCT5k

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes: `'` instead of double quotes `"`. In Kotlin (and Java) single quotes are used for `Char`s, not for `String`s.
You have to use `"`, like:

```
"$NumberofTouches touch"
```